# Cannot find tag library descriptor error: displaytag & spring

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I get three errors in 2 of my .jsp pages namely:

Line 1:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="/spring" %>
```

Error message: Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/spring"

Line 2:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/" prefix="display" %>
```

Error message:
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://
     displaytag.sourceforge.net/"
    - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://
     displaytag.sourceforge.net/"

Am I missing a specific .jar file in my project?

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing a specific .jar file in my project? thanks

Yes, the JAR file(s) containing TLD files listening on the specified URI's. Either that, or the URI is simply invalid. Consult the documentation of the library in question for the exact URI.

I don't do [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) nor [Displaytag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net), but you likely need to install Spring and Displaytag in your webapp. It's basically just downloading the JAR files from their homepages and dropping them in `/WEB-INF/lib`. That should be it. Do **not** extract the JAR files and put loose TLD files in the classpath, this is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Just to understand it fully, when I simply drop the jar into `WEB-INF/lib`, I do not need to specify the `taglib` right?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you are either missing .tld files in your WEB-INF directory, or you are specifying a wrong uri in your taglib directive. Double check the uri value, this should be the same as the one specified in the  tag in the .tld file of your custom tags.